# Searchable textbox and vba highlights row from continuous form and brings record to top with rest of records to follow

Tags: vba, ms-access, search

I have a form I want to use as a guide to search for a record then pull the record up to the top form as a highlighted line with the rest of the records to follow. Additionally, I want the searchable text box that I'm searching in to automatically jump to the next record without hitting enter or clearing the textbox. I want that part to be automated. So I would be continuously entering in numbers for thousands of records and looking up their information.

Some other info, my form is non-editable but the text box is.

I've tried using a form with some code but can't get it gives me an error saying my private sub is not recognized as a valid field name or expression.

```
Private Sub Recsch_AfterUpdate()
   On Error GoTo Err_ErrorHandler

   Dim ItemSelected As String

       ItemSelected = Forms![Inventory_Status].Recsch
       Recsch = Null
       Me.Filter = "[RecId] = '" & ItemSelected & "'"
       Me.FilterOn = True

Err_ErrorHandler:
       Exit Sub
End Sub
```

[image]

I just want my code to take me to the next line of the form without having to click anywhere. So it would enter in the data on the box, search in my form, highlight the line, bring it to the top, then highlight my box again so I can enter the next number without pressing enter.

Comment: Have to press Enter key in order to invoke the AfterUpdate event. Is RecID a text field? Exactly which line errors? Disable the On Error GoTo line then set a breakpoint and step through code. If you want all records to still show then don't use Filter method.

Comment: RecID is a numeric field. When I click the blank box to type it gives me the my Recsch is not recognized as a valid field name or expression.

Comment: What is the name of the textbox (should`be Recsch`) ? Add`Option Explicit`on top of (every) code module. Put `Me.`in front of `Recsch`to make clear it ist a form member not a variable (you can replace`Forms![Inventory_Status].Recsch` with `Me.Recsch`too).

Comment: I got it to work, I needed to create a new form

Comment: That sounds like Event Handler was not registered (Textbox`OnClick`property Should be`[Event Procedure]`)

Comment: And what about the highlight and record on top part of the question? Your code just filters for the search record, others are not displayed!

Comment: If RecID is a number field, don't use apostrophe delimiters for the parameter.